# jquery mobile and ajax slow performance

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I have problem with jquery mobile when the information comes from Ajax requests. It happens with `listview` and `collapsible`. The problem is that I have a list with about 500 titles and before I use `.listview()` it's working fine. But when I put `.listview` in the end it takes about 1 minute to load all he list elements and 2 times appears a message to ask me whether to stop the jquery script.

What should I do? Is there a way I can use jquery mobile listview styling and keep speed performance?